# Can't log in when I block cookies in Chrome

Tags: support, login

I am getting error on StackOverflow.com after disabling cookies in Chrome:

> Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is
>   denied for this document.

[image]

Is it necessary that we have to cookies enabled?

Comment: Looks like a XY problem. Why do you want to block cookies in the first place?

Comment: To confirm: our login system uses cookies. With cookies disabled, feel free to browse the site - but: you won't be able to log in. Please see "If you don’t like cookies or have other dietary restrictions" [here](https://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy)

Comment: If you're blocking all cookies, I don't think you understand at all what they are. Try reading up on what cookies are used for and why most sites depend on them to function properly.

Comment: Any alternative to session cookies would also have very similar privacy implications, so it would be only effort without any gain. Anyone paranoid and motivated enough could also just examine all cookies SE places, and selectively allow only session cookies.

Comment: Long story short it's not a bug it's a feature, or say it's a feature that SO (reasonably) don't bother to support. Been supported cookieless session before, it's a hell of a mess and when we finally decided to abandon it I literally cried.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, logging into this site without cookies is not supported.

From the [privacy policy](https://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy):

> A cookie is a string of information that a website stores on a visitor’s computer, and that the visitor’s browser provides to the website each time the visitor returns. We use cookies to help us track visitors’ use of the network and their preferences. If you do not wish to have cookies placed on your computer, you should set your browser to refuse cookies, **but should be aware that certain features of the network may not function properly without them.**

(Bold emphasis mine)

and from the [central FAQ on what browsers are supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need):

> There are requirements beyond using a modern browser for getting the best possible experience:
>
> - JavaScript must be enabled.
> - **Cookies must be enabled.**
> - Images must not be blocked. (Since CSS Sprites are widely used.)
>
> [.. more requirements ..]

While it may be *technically* possible to offer the similar functionality without using cookies, such techniques are much harder to implement, and are far more brittle. It would require that a session ID is added to *all URLs on the site*, which would hurt cachability, and is very easy to get wrong. This would raise the  cost of developing and operating this site, money I'd much rather see used for improving the site in other ways.